# ¿Cómo hacer que funcione en MS-Access un código SQL que funciona en SQL Server?

Tags: sql

El siguiente código SQL funciona en SQL Server:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DELETE FROM Tabla1
   WHERE CampoClave = '4'
   DELETE FROM Tabla2
   WHERE CampoClave = '4'
COMMIT;
```

CampoClave es alfanumérico. Si cambio las comillas simples por dobles y lo ejecuto en MS-Access, en diseño de consulta - SQL, no funciona.
Por favor, ¿alguna sugerencia para que funcione en MS-Access?

Comment: Yo probaria a poner un punto y coma después de cada sentencia DELETE

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración. He probado tu sugerencia, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que no funciona? ¿No hace lo que debe de hacero produce un error? Si produce un error, ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: Cuando se ejecuta el código en cuestión, Access responde con el siguiente mensaje: Instrucción SQL no válida; se esperaba 'DELETE', 'INSERT', PROCEDURE', 'SELECT' o 'UPDATE'

Comment: Por favor, ve a [edit] tu pregunta e indica cómo estás ejecutándolo en access. Desde un código VBA? En un cliente? Posiblemente esa forma de ejecutarlo falla al encontrar la declaración del bloquede  transacción, no por sintaxis sino por cómo se ejecuta. Y para futuras oportunidades, los avances, cambios y datos adicionales (como **el mensaje de error** de cada intento) van EN la pregunta porque en los comentarios se pierden

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.